# Remove Value When an option is deselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Edit:: What I am trying to achieve is I am getting each `option text` not the `value`, so I can send it to an API. Getting the text from the select works perfectly. I want to remove it when I deselect an option from the `input value` when I click it again. For example if I select multiple I get `Medit-4-packs, Swiss-Gear-Bag` When I click it one by one it removes it but when I deselect multiple I get the value of another. I want to replace the value as empty when deselected like usual. Hope it helps to clarify

Any help on using jquery to deselect Select option from input value?  These are what I have tried so far. Thanks for help

Trying to remove the values in the `<input>` when option gets deselected.

`<input class="form-check-input" type="text" value="" id="equipment" name="equipmentitems" >`

```
 <select multiple class="image-picker show-labels show-html" data-limit="16"  name="packages[]" id="group_psoft">
<option value=" " data-img-class="first" selected></option>
<option data-img-src="/images/" data-img-label="Scanner Tips(4Pcs)" name="packs" data-img-alt="KeepSame" value="400" >Medit-4-packs</option>
<option data-img-src="/images/" data-img-label="SwissGear Bag" name="bagoriginal" data-img-alt="Aggresive" value="200"> Swiss-Gear-Bag</option> 
</select>
```

Js

```
$('.image-picker').imagepicker({
   show_label: true,
   limit: 15,

//This is setting the text in the input
   selected: function($items) {
     $('#equipment').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
   },

// Here I want to remove it if clicked again
   changed: function(){
      $('#equipment').val($(this).unbind('option:selected').text()); // This removes it but add all the other options text in the input

 $('#equipment').val($(this).unbind('option:selected').val( )); // Here It removes it but I get the value of the next selected option. 

     $('#equipment').val($(this).unbind('option:selected').text(' ' )); This I get Js [object,object]

   }

});
```

Comment: Please add some more details in your question its hard to understand what you want when I look at your codes, it would be enough to post only `name="packages[]"` instead of trying to get each option values separetly.

Comment: Name="packages[]" gets me values in $S_REQUEST, it does not get me the text label. So I send it all to an ```input[text]``` then I send it to the server. I use php to manipulate the data afterwards

Comment: See change() function here : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref  not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it when I move the code outside the function. I also changed `unbind()` to `on()` method.

```
$('.image-picker').on('change', function() {
  $('#equipment').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it works out.

```
$('.image-picker').imagepicker({
   show_label: true,
   limit: 15,

//This is setting the text in the input
   selected: function($items) {
     $('#equipment').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
   },

// Here I want to remove it if clicked again
   changed: function(){
      var equiValue = $('#equipment').val();
      var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
      if(equiValue === selectedValue) {
        $('#equipment').val("");
      }

   }

});
```